# Data Type Conversion causing error in SSIS Package

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-update, global-temp-tables

I have an SSIS package that has a step that creates a temp table using a Execute SQL Task.

Inside of this query I have a case statement that is something like:

```
Cast(Case
    When billing_address is Like '%DONOTUSE%' Then 1
    When billing_address is Like '%DONTUSE%' Then 1 
Else 0
End as nvarchar)DoNotUseAccounts
```

I have an update statement in a different Execute SQL Task that is like this:

```
Update #StatementAccounts 
Set Issues = Issues + ' - Do Not Use Account' 
Where Product In ('prod1','prod2','prod3','prod4') 
     And DoNotUseCustomer= 1
```

When executing the package I am receiving an error: "Error: String or binary data would be truncated."

Am I using the wrong data type?

Does the Update statement need to be cast/converted as well?

Any guidance would be helpful.

I have tried using datatype int, numeric, and Casting the update statement as an int as well.

Comment: What's the data type of `#StatementAccounts.Issues`?

Comment: Hi, the data type is converted to nvarchar.

Comment: you don't have a length on nvarchar something like nvarchar(100)

Comment: if you have any Issue that is already at max length of datatype, this will blow up because you are adding len( ' - Do Not Use Account') chars to the end of it

Comment: the fix goes back to creating the temp table and extending the length of Issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one of two possible issues here.

1) You have an explicit `CREATE TABLE #StatementAccounts` statement where you're defining `Issues` as `NVARCHAR` with no length specified, in which case it's one character, or with a length that's too small to accommodate the additional characters that you're trying to append with your `UPDATE` statement.

FIX: Make the declaration at least `len( ' - Do Not Use Account')` characters longer.

2) Much more likely from the sound of things, you're using a `SELECT...INTO #StatementAccounts` statement and letting SQL Server define your data types for you. In this case, it's setting `Issues` to be just big enough to accommodate the largest value in that initial statement.

FIX: Issue an explicit `CREATE TABLE #StatementAccounts` statement and declare appropriately sized data types, then change the `SELECT...INTO` to an `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: It worked! Your assumption was correct, I did not have a defined length for Nvarchar in "Issues". Thank you!